# Hubot windows service

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, hubot, node-windows

I would like to wrap my Hubot in a windows service to deploy it.

I am using [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) to do this but I'm having some trouble trying to get it to run a coffee-script file (which is what hubot uses).

If i manually run

```
> coffee .\node_modules\hubot\bin\hubot
```

everything works fine.

But I cant work out how to call this from a node-windows script. My attempt below:

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

var svc = new Service({
  name:'Hubot',
  description: 'Hubot',
  script: 'coffee .\\hubot\\node_modules\\hubot\\bin\\hubot'
});

svc.on('install',function(){
  svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

which fails with the following:

> C:\Users\luke.mcgregor\hubot>node app.js fs.js:747   return
>   binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
>                    ^ Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\luke.mcgregor\hubot\coffee
>   .\hubot\node_modules\hubot\bin\daemon'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:747:18)
>       at C:\Users\luke.mcgregor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-windows\lib\daemon.js:409:16
>       at FSReqWrap.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:226:19)

Comment: Have you tried using forever to run it (https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)
Is there a rigid dependency to run it as a service so you can run it as a specific user?

Answer (score 1):

The `script` is not a command, only the path to a file. You can change the executable used by node-windows to run your scripts by setting an `execPath` environment variable: https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows/issues/61#issuecomment-51423542